# Combine several Typescript files to a single JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to combine several Typescript files to a single JS file, without any module system of any kind. Basically, I have files like this:

```js
// Main.ts
import { foo } from "./foo";

function main() {
    console.log("main");
    foo();
}

// foo.ts
export function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

And I want to produce a single JS file like this:

```
// out.js
function main() {
    console.log("main");
    foo();
}

function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

(the reason for this is that the code is for a Cosmos DB stored procedure, which has to be a single file with no imports).

**In my tsconfig.json, I set `module` to `none` and `outFile` to `./out.js`. But when I build, it doesn't do anything. No error, but out.js is not emitted.**

(Apparently `outFile` can only be used with `system` or `amd` modules, and it gives an error if I try with any other module system. But with `none`, there's no error, which leads me to believe it's a valid combination.)

Is there a way to achieve what I want? If it can't be done with only Typescript, I'm open to other options (gulp, maybe?).

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm very new to Typescript and I know very little about which tools are available. I know there are other questions about this, but none of the answers have worked for me.

Comment: I think you have to use webpack. As far as I know, tsc is only responsible of compiling the files not bundling them

Comment: Why don't you want to use a module bundler system? Not *that* experienced with this sort of thing, but I thought they were required in order to turn multiple files into a single bundle

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I didn't say I didn't want that ;)
I don't know anything about the TS/JS ecosystem, I don't know what options are available to me.

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı how do I do that?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you can follow the link: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this using a Gulp script that concatenates everything into a single file. Here it is, in all its ugliness:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const path = require("path");
const flatmap = require("gulp-flatmap");
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task("build-cosmos-stored-procedures", function() {
    const sharedScripts = "CosmosServerScriptHelpers/*.ts";
    const tsServerSideScripts = "CosmosStoredProcedures/**/*.ts";

    return gulp.src(tsServerSideScripts)
        .pipe(flatmap((stream, file) =>
        {
            let outFile = path.join(path.dirname(file.relative), path.basename(file.relative, ".ts") + ".js");
            let tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
            return stream
                .pipe(gulp.src(sharedScripts))
                .pipe(tsProject())
                .pipe(replace(/^\s*import .+;$\s*/gm, ""))
                .pipe(replace(/^\s*export .+;$\s*/gm, ""))
                .pipe(replace(/^\s*export /gm, " "))
                .pipe(concat(outFile))
                .pipe(gulp.dest("CosmosStoredProcedures"));
        }));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("build-cosmos-stored-procedures"));
```

Basically what it does is:
- take each TS file from the stored procedures folder (a.ts, b.ts, etc)
- compile each of these files separately with the shared scripts
- concatenate the output files into a single file (a.js, b.js, etc)
- each output file contains the output of the original source, plus the output of all the shared scripts

The regex replacements remove any "import" or "export" stuff, as Cosmos DB requires each stored procedure to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with `module` values other than `none`. Even in your combined single file the JS needs *some* way to define and encapsulate the code from the separate files. I'd start with trying `--module= UMD`. UMD means "universal module definition", and just defines a way for code blocks to be wrapped in isolated scopes and access each other from within one file - it doesn't require a runtime supported module system (like CommonJS or ES6 modules) on the target platform.

Comment: Experiment with some other module formats them, maybe `AMD`? Failing that, try bundling with Webpack as suggested in the other comments.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work for me, I really need it to use no module system at all. Just put everything in the same file. I'll give Webpack a try.

Comment: Webpack also generates too much stuff. I eventually did it with a (pretty ugly) Gulp script.